# Find all polynomials $Q(x)(x^2-6x+8) =Q(x-2)(x^2-6x)$ for $x\in \Bbb R$

Tags: polynomials

> Find all polynomials $Q(x)(x^2-6x+8) =Q(x-2)(x^2-6x)$ for $x\in \Bbb R$

I've tried different substitutions like put $Q(x)$ $=$ $k$ for some $k$ and getting the equation $k(x^2-6x+8)$ $=$ $(k-2)(x^2-6x)$ $<=>$ $k$=$(6x-x^2)/4$, but that doesn't give equlity. Thank you for your help

Comment: What substitutions have you tried? Showing us what you have done may help people point out what to try next or spot if you have made any mistakes

Comment: If you substitute $Q(x) = k$, the right hand side should be $k(x^2 - 6x)$.

Comment: How is the Right hand side equal to $k(x^2-6x)$?

Comment: If $Q(x) = k$, replacing $x$ by $x-2$ on both sides, $Q(x-2) = k$.

Comment: If thats the case then $8$ $=$ $0$

Comment: I mean like some number $k$ so that it is a polynomial and replacing it with $k-2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
(x^2-6x+8) Q(x) &\equiv (x^2 -6x)Q(x-2)\\
(x^2 - 6x)[Q(x)-Q(x-2)] &\equiv -8Q(x)
\end{align*}$$

If $Q(x)$ has degree $n > 0$, $Q(x) - Q(x-2)$ has degree $n-1$, and so the left hand side has degree $n+1$. However, the right hand side has degree $n$.

So $n\not>0$, and $Q(x)$ can only be a constant function with degree $0$. Let $Q(x) \equiv q$,

$$\begin{align*}
(x^2-6x+8)q &\equiv (x^2 -6x)q\\
8q &\equiv 0\\
q &\equiv 0\\
Q(x) &\equiv 0
\end{align*}$$

---

Notes regarding that $Q(x) - Q(x-2)$ has degree $n-1$: Let
$$Q(x) \equiv ax^n + bx^{n-1} + \cdots$$
where $a \ne 0$ and all lower degree terms are omitted. Then $Q(x-2)$ is

$$\begin{align*}
Q(x-2) &\equiv a(x^n - 2nx^{n-1} + \cdots) + b(x^{n-1} - \cdots) + \cdots\\
&\equiv ax^n -2anx^{n-1} + bx^{n-1} + \cdots\\
Q(x)-Q(x-2)&\equiv 2anx^{n-1} + \cdots
\end{align*}$$

Since $a\ne 0$ and $n> 0$, the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is non-zero, and so the right hand side has degree $n-1$.

Comment: If this only was a part of the problem and I now got $P(x)$ $=$ $Q(x)(x-4)(x-2)x(x+2)$ then we get that $P(x)$ $=$ $0$?

Comment: @MathFanatics right.

Answer (score 1):

maybe Hint:Some information come out from $Q(x)(x^2-6x+8) =Q(x-2)(x^2-6x)$
$$x=0 \to Q(0)(8)=Q(-2)0 \to Q(0)=0\\
x=6 \to Q(6)(8)=Q(6-2)0 \to Q(6)=0\\
x=4 \to Q(4)(0)=Q(2)(16-24) \to Q(4)=0$$ so $Q(x)$ at least  contain $$Q(x)=(x-0)(x-4)(x-6)$$ or 
$$Q(x)=(x-0)(x-6)(x-4)q(x)$$

Comment: I've tried that, but it only gives q(x)(x^2-8x+16)=q(x-2)(x^2-14x+48)

Comment: This is not the end; substitute $x = 8$,
$$24 Q(8) = 16Q(6) \implies Q(8) =0$$
Keep going, all larger positive even integral $x$ gives $Q(x)= 0$. Since $Q$ is a polynomial with infinite number of roots, $Q(x) = 0$.

Comment: I don't want to Go on forever :)